# Perl - Win32::Gui - Determin text content of text field which has focus

Tags: perl, win32gui

I have defined a main window `$mw` on which I placed several text fields in which an user can provide information.
As soon as the user presses RETURN I want to determin the field which had the focus at that time and read out its text content to process it further.

Here is the code how I defined the text fields:

```
$mw->AddLabel (
    -name   => "lblSAP",
    -top    => 5,
    -left   => 10,
    -width  => 80,
    -text   => "identity no.",
);

$mw->AddTextfield (               # text field 1
    -name   => "txtSAP",
    -pos    => [ 5, 20 ],
    -size   => [ 80, 20 ],
    -tabstop    => 1,
);

$mw->AddLabel (
    -name   => "lblDokar",
    -top    => 5,
    -left   => 95,
    -width  => 40,
    -text   => "dokar",
);

$mw->AddTextfield (               # text field 2 (there are more)
    -name   => "txtDokar",
    -pos    => [ 90, 20 ],
    -size   => [ 40, 20 ],
    -tabstop    => 1,
    -text   => 'DRW',
);
```

I have tried method `GetFocus()` which returns a handle but I don't know how to use this handle to get the text from the textfield (I even don't know whether the method returned the handle of the main window or the control which got the focust :-(.

I tried it like so:

```
my $handle = $mw->GetFocus();    # get handle of the focusse control
my $txt_text = $handle->Text();   # get text of the focussed control
```

That didn't work.

Have I overlooked a method which returns the name instead of the handle or how can one access the controls by their handle?